# How to check in Makefile that gcc supports -fopenmp-simd flag?

Tags: gcc, makefile

I want to check in a Makefile that gcc supports -fopenmp-simd flag.
This flag enables support of OpenMP 4.0 pragmas.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
is_fopenmp_simd_supported := $(shell touch foo.c && gcc -fopenmp-simd -c foo.c -o foo.o &> /dev/null && echo 'yes'; rm -f foo.c foo.o)
$(info is_fopenmp_simd_supported=$(is_fopenmp_simd_supported))
all:
```